# How can I build a docker-compose image while using git?

Tags: git, docker, docker-compose

I’m looking to upgrade my app to run with docker-compose rather than using systemd unit files with docker. However my web app uses git so there is no `.yml` file on my server. Every time I try to build a docker-compose image, my `.yml` file can’t be found on the server. It returns:

```
ERROR:
    Can't find a suitable configuration file in this directory or any
    parent. Are you in the right directory?

    Supported filenames: docker-compose.yml, docker-compose.yaml
```

How can I build a docker-compose image while using a git remote repo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to generate a `docker-compose.yml` file (or copy it from an external referential) on your server.

That can be achieve through a [post-receive (server-side) hook](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks#_server_side_hooks) which can ensure, each time a new commit is pushed that:

- the `docker-compose.yml` is still there
- if not, copy/generate it